# OCaml - Keeping a visual timer

Tags: ocaml

I'm making a sudoku game with in OCaml with the [Graphics library](http://caml.inria.fr/pub/docs/manual-ocaml/libref/Graphics.html).

I'm trying to add a timer at the top so that the player can see how long he's taking to solve the sudoku. I've looked around and the [Lwt library](http://ocsigen.org/lwt/) seems to be what I'm looking for.

To draw the timer I wrote a function draw_time, the content of the function is too long and not important, but it has this kind of structure:

```
let rec hello () = 
    Lwt.bind (Lwt_unix.sleep 14400.) 
       (fun () -> print_endline "Hello, world !"; hello ())
Lwt.async (hello)
```

I've tested it and the function does work as it's supposed to.

The main loop of my game looks like this:

```
let main_loop gs f_init f_end f_key f_mouse = 

    f_init;
        let timer = draw_time () in
        try 
            while true do
                try 
                    if gs.completed <> true then
                        let event = Graphics.wait_next_event event_types in
                            if event.Graphics.keypressed then 
                                f_key event.Graphics.key
                            else if event.Graphics.button then 
                                f_mouse event.Graphics.mouse_x event.Graphics.mouse_y               
                with 
                | _ -> raise End
            done
        with 
        | End  -> f_end () 
    ;;
```

This doesn't seem to work. The program only executes draw_time when I close the window (and the program) and not when the window is open and the timer is supposed to be drawn.

What am I doing wrong exactly?

Comment: It's a bit under-specified, please show the definition of `draw_time`.

Comment: I don't think that's needed since the problem is not in draw_time. If I call hello instead of draw_time, it's the exact same issue. The program starts printing "Hello, world !" every second right ever I shut-down the program and not while the program is running.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to run Lwt program, you need to start the [main loop](http://ocsigen.org/lwt/2.4.8/manual/), that will process your threads,

```
let () = Lwt_main.run (Lwt_io.printl "Hello, world!")
```

Lwt has code that will integrate Lwt main loop into the Glib. But, as far as I know, there is no such integration for Graphics module.

You may find [async_graphics](https://github.com/lpw25/async_graphics/) interesting, it is an integration of the Async library, that is quite near to Lwt with Graphics module. It was even mentioned in [Real World OCaml](https://realworldocaml.org/v1/en/html/classes.html)